# NUnit cannot start running unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I have the following problem when I try to run some unit tests written using NUnit:

[image: NUnit Error]

Strangely, I have managed to run successfully these unit tests before, but for some reason, after some interaction with the Source Control Provider, now I get this error.

The full error message is the following:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.BeginRun(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean captureTrace, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.BeginRun(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, Boolean tracing, LoggingThreshold logLevel)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.RunTests(ITestFilter filter)
   at NUnit.UiKit.TestSuiteTreeView.RunTests(ITest[] tests, Boolean ignoreCategories)
   at NUnit.Gui.NUnitForm.runButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5477 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
nunit
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/nunit.exe
----------------------------------------
nunit-gui-runner
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit-gui-runner.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.core
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit.core.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.util
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit.util.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.core.interfaces
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit.core.interfaces.DLL
----------------------------------------
nunit.uikit
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit.uikit.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
nunit.uiexception
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.6.3.13283
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NUnit%202.6.3/bin/lib/nunit.uiexception.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5479 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
zb-hwpsa
    Assembly Version: 2.6.3.13283
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Does someone experienced this error before?

Thanks, 
Ionut

Comment: The FileNotFoundException is for System.Configuration version 4.0.0.0, but the loaded assemblies are version 2.0.0.0; has the targetted .NET framework changed?

Comment: I think someone change your solution parameters to use other version of your .Net framework.

Comment: Nope, the Unit Test Project targets .NET Fw 4.5.

Comment: Another thing to check is whether Test Runner is the same processor architecture as the assembly being tested (esp if the tested assembly isn't MSIL) - [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399972/nunit-could-not-load-file-or-assemby-mytestproject)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244132/1181624 - Had the same error, this was the fix.